# CSS3 - span tag moving text downward after :before content has been removed

Tags: html, css

I have this checkbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/2WZWW/

As you can see, when it's checked, the text appears inside of the box, and everything looks okay. But as soon as you click on it to uncheck it, the content of the box disappears (good thing), but `Description` is going down. How do I prevent this text to go down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to the pseudo-element is one way - the default [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) value for elements in the [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) is `baseline` and when the text disappears it's changing it's position based on the baseline of the text.

```
.form input[type="checkbox"] ~ label span:before {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2WZWW/1/